# UTF-8 to UTF-16 API wrapper libraries for Windows?

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

Is there any wrapper library out there that mimics the Windows "ANSI" function names (e.g. `CreateFileA`), assumes the inputs are in UTF-8, converts them to UTF-16, calls the UTF-16 version of the function (e.g. `CreateFileW`), and converts the outputs back to UTF-8 for the program?

It would allow ASCII programs to use UTF-8 almost seamlessly.

Comment: AFAIK - no, there're too many Windows API functions.

Comment: You can convert an *ASCII* string into UTF-16 trivially.

Comment: It's probably simplest to bite the bullet and use the UTF-16 versions of the Windows API functions everywhere.  If you the strings are coming from UTF-8 sources, it's probably easier to wrap *those*.

Comment: @valdo: Yeah I was thinking the same thing, but just wanted to ask in case there was one I didn't know about.

Comment: File a bug with Microsoft that CP_ACP can't be set CP_UTF8. If it could then the A functions would work fine and you wouldn't need a wrapper library.

Comment: Microsoft is well aware that people would like to use UTF-8 for `CP_ACP`, but I doubt it'd ever happen. https://web.archive.org/web/20080916173536/http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2006/10/11/816996.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Rather than wrapping the API functions, it's easier to wrap the strings in a conversion function. Then you'll be future-proof when the next version of Windows adds more API functions.

Comment: I'd hate to -1, but this is really not answering the question. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad, that's your right. While it might not be the answer to the question as asked, it *is* the answer to the problem behind the question.

Comment: That's assuming you have access to the source code. But if you had a library like this, you wouldn't need the source code -- you could just compile the library as a DLL and redirect the functions at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, there are too many WinAPI functions to make such a library feasible. However one can hack it on the tool-chain level or using something like http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/.

**EDIT:** [Windows 10 added support for UTF-8 codepage in ANSI API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page).

Answer (score 0):

There is this thing called [WDL](http://www.cockos.com/wdl/), it has some UTF-8 wrappers (win32_utf8). I have never tried it so I don't know how complete the support is.

Comment: It only seems to have wrappers for a handful of functions (about ~30).